# How can I combine 4 images into an A4 image via the console?

Tags: command-line, image-processing

I am working on a Photo-booth installation, and I want to take 4 photos (I have figured this bit out), and then combine them so they are on an A4 paper sheet ready to be printed.

I need to do this through the console, so I can automate the whole process.
I have looked at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), but I can only figure out how to overlay the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/montage.html) command. I haven't got any examples to hand, but I've used it in the past, and there are some good examples at the link and also [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#tile):

Comment: this worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I've used

```
convert *.png result.pdf
```

and then used evince's option to print 4 pages per sheet.

Maybe this can point you in a viable direction.